# How to retrieve my IntelliJ IDEA/PhpStorm configuration after PC crash (from backup disk)?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

My Windows 7 has crashed. All my projects have disappeared from my PhpStorm IDE. My IDE settings (colors, shortcuts) have been reset to initial values.

There are still `.idea` folders inside my projects.

I have made a full backup of my whole hard disk: what files should I restore to have my IDE back (projects list, shortcuts, theme..) ?

Comment: What's you IDE and its version? You have stated PhpStorm .. but at the same time you also stated IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration files you're looking for are in your home folder (`~/.PhpStorm2016.3`) (see [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/project-and-ide-settings.html#d932721e81)). I'd suggest [using Settings Repository to sync/backup your config using git](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#d352821e37).